# No networks are available on Kali Linux Network-Manager

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm using VB with the latest update of kali linux and yet when i look for wirless networks with the networkmanager it doesn't show any network.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwd5L.jpg)

Why?
Regards pzmq

## EDIT

VB stands for VirtualBox sorry for not saying that from the beghinning

[Specs of the wirless device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Apo.jpg)
I was once able to see the networks but i started messing around with monitor mode and i think i screw something up.

Even when i try 'airodump-ng wlan0mon' it accepts the monitor mode and the interface but when it scans ,doesn't find anything.

Comment: I personally don't know Kali Linux, but here's some suggestions for getting a good response : spell carefully, capitalize carefully, expand your acronyms (VB says VisualBasic to me), say what hardware you're using, and say conclusively that you've gotten connected with an adjacent wireless device.  Note any special circumstances about the wireless network (the PS4 can't see our PEAP network for instance).  Including the image is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming VB means Oracle VirtualBox and you have a Kali Linux guest running on that.

If I'm correct then the reason you can't see wireless networks in the Kali guest is because VirtualBox emulates your physical Wireless NIC as a wired or paravirtualized NIC to the guest. Kali believes it is connected to a wired network, and as such it cannot enumerate through polling the WiFi networks.

You would have to successfully configure hardware passthrough, which may not work for your hardware. It would also make your WiFI NIC unavailable to the host operating system.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough

If you just want Kali to have a network connection through your WiFi NIC then simply use NAT networking for your Kali guest and connect the host OS to whatever WiFi network you are allowed to and want to.

If you want to use Kali's wireless networking security tools for legitimate purposes then you should probably boot it on "bare metal" off a removable device (USB typically).

Comment: Thanks for the tips and i'm connecting trow 2 situations(not exectly the best i supose)

Comment: 1 through a NAT in order to give the machine an internet connection whether i'm connectet the 2ª way or not. 2 I have an wifi usb (for testing porpuse) that is also connected through VB to Kali

Comment: USB passthrough for VirtualBox is much easier, and would allow the guest to see the WiFi NIC as a WiFi NIC. If that is what you are doing, and "lspci | grep net" shows it as a WiFi NIC then the problem is with the guest configuration. You'll have to check the NIC's driver and mode since you were previously changing the mode to monitor. You want managed mode (sometimes called client or station).

Comment: i don't know the command 'lspci' but i just executed "lspci | grep net" and it didn't output anything.was it suppost to?

Comment: `lspci | grep` think of the first command as "list PCI," just in case the spelling was wrong. Without any redirection or arguments is lists most of the hardware devices attached to your computer. Piping it to grep to search for lines containing "net" should list all the NICs on a Linux computer. Because you are using a USB NIC the `lsusb` command may also be useful in determining if your hardware is present in the guest.